# Emacs load extra configuration by command

Tags: emacs

I am a Emacs user, and have a long configuration file (.emacs) by default. But now I need to add some extra configuration for some specific project. I wonder how I could archive it.

To be more specific:

I have a default .emacs file in the ~/ folder.  Now for a specific project under ~/project/, I have a specific Makefile under the project folder, I hope I could press one a default compile key to make it.

I prefer to write another small configuration file in the project folder, and manually load it when I am working in this project. But I don't know how to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: If `M-x compile` is not already sufficient (it runs `make -k` by default), you can specify a different value for the `compile-command` variable under that project's directory, via [Directory Local Variables](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables).

Comment: Thanks! I have solved this problem by using the .dir-locals.el file.